# How to get rid of extra spaces before and after commas on R Shiny text output?

Tags: r, shiny, removing-whitespace

I am wondering how to get rid of extra spaces that appear on the text output of my R Shiny App.

This is how it has been coded:

```
output$summary <- renderText ({
  isolate({
    paste("The power of this independent samples t-test, with population means of", 
          input$mu_1,"and", input$mu_2,
          ", standard deviations of", input$sigma_1, "and", input$sigma_2, 
          ", and sample sizes of", input$N_1, "and", input$N_2, ", is", Power)
  })
})


Power = mean(out.df$p.value < .05)

Power})
```

}

on the app, however, it comes out like:

The power of this independent samples t-test, with population means of 10 and 13 , standard deviations of 2 and 5 , and sample sizes of 21 and 27 , is 0.770562770562771

As you can see, there are extra spaces that appear before the commas and I am wondering how I can get rid of those? I have tried sep = "" but that just bunches all of the numbers together. Not sure if I am putting it in the right place?

Anyway, thanks in advance!

Margot

Answer (score 2):

Use, `sep = ""` with defined spaces in text,

```
paste("The power of this independent samples t-test, with population means of ", 
  input$mu_1," and ", input$mu_2,
  ", standard deviations of ", input$sigma_1, " and ", input$sigma_2, 
  ", and sample sizes of ", input$N_1, " and ", input$N_2, ", is ", Power, sep = "")

# [1] "The power of this independent samples t-test, with population means of 1 and 1, 
# standard deviations of 1 and 1, and sample sizes of 1 and 1, is 1"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my issue!! :)

Answer (score 2):

The defautl value for sep in the paste function is " ". You should use either `paste0` (which has no sep value) or set `sep=""` inside the `paste` call.